# OauthのコールバックURLはlocalhostでも良い?

Tags: oauth

OauthのコールバックURLは`localhost`でもいいのでしょうか?

Providerがリクエストトークンを発行すると同時にコールバックURLにリダイレクトされますが、
このコールバックURLは`localhost`でもいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

開発用ということであればそれでいいと思います。